# Ephemeral ECC refresh vs. simple hash ratchet

Tags: public-key, protocol-design, key-exchange

Some protocols employ ephemeral ECC key exchanges throughout the session. Such as the Noise framework.

Is the rationale to do this simply because you can do it efficiently?

To provide future secrecy wouldn't all you need is a simple hash function to ratchet the symmetric encryption key?

Seems like the only value for redoing the asymmetric encryption step repeatedly is a "healing" property that is sometimes mentioned in the literature. But what this properly aims to mitigate appears to be practically dubious, a scenario is which a compromise is ephemeral and happens and withdraws in-session. Can such a thing even happen in real life?

Comment: It provides forward secrecy, where the leakage of the key doesn't impact the confidentiality of future messages. Sure you can argue if those session keys are already secure, but the theory behind the protocol is known, right?

Comment: On the security, model: this is indeed a strong attacker model. But the security contracts of most of cryptographic scheme can also be seen mostly "unrealistic". AES-GCM is an AEAD, the powers given to the adversary by the AEAD definition is rarely fully realistic, yet AEAD security is necessary in many real world cases. The wisdom is: if it's cheap to achieve stronger notions, there's no harm in doing so as long as it's understood what is being done. As for the real-world-ness of the model. Temporary access to state is absolutely realistic in several ways that I describe later.

Comment: There are many cases where foothold cannot be persisted. One comes across many cases where you can have a reverse shell only for a short period, allowing to extract some state only during that time. Alternatively, foothold may only hold until an EDR detects the threat and blocks further access. Migrating to another device upon suspicious is another example, so is temporary failure in randomness generation. The point is that a simple symmetric ratchet is unsatisfactory even against a weak adversary who can afford state reveal only once.

Comment: What ephemeral key exchange afford us is also making sure that even such a "weak" adversary can't learn more than they should. It's good to clarify here that in TLS for instance, ephemerals have nothing to do with healing this is just about forward secrecy. But it's true that ephemerals can be used to also provide healing like mechanisms. This is why signal uses both symmetric ratchets and asymmetric ratchet to achieve different goals.